# How to share SQL Server 2008 R2 using WiFi?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008

I want to share my SQL Server 2008 R2 database between some computers on the same network(WiFi). How can I do so?
 I mean I just want two users access the same Database through a network(WiFI). Both can use database, update database, delete data from database is it possible ?
 I am using Windows application C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? What is not working?

The most straight forward solution is to access the database by a SQL  authentication (user/password) and use connection string similar to below where datasource is your database local IP address

```
<add name="connectionstring"  connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.x;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password   ..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: i have already tried connection my computer with database at same computer..

this is my coding
 ' private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    string connectionString = @"Server=ABEDH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=HL7;Integrated Security=SSPI";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM FROMPenerima";  '
        
           now, what must i do at my another computer? i want my another computer can acces database it(ABEDH-PC\SQLEXPRESS) too.

Comment: **1)** Aren't you using Windows Authentication on the SQL server (it authenticates you by your logged user, so you don't have to provide username/password). Use SQL Authentication -  Create a user in Databse, give him permissions to your HL7 database. Use this username and password as `USER Id` and `Password` in your connection string. Check if this works on _your_ computer. Than check the same thing on the _other_ one.

**2)** Have you tried accessing that database from another computer in SQL Managment Studio or _Server Browser_ in Visual Studio? Can you see the database? Can you access it?

Comment: 1) Okay now i have already create username and password. This is work on my computer. i can acces my database.(username : ahay, password : ahay) 2) I can't accessing that database from another computer. this is my query [
select * from openrowset('SQLOledb', '192.168.1.1';'ahay';'ahay','select *from HL7..FromPenerima')]. 192.168.1.1 is ip address another computer, my computer and another computer have already connect to same WiFi. is there something wrong with my query? @Mike Nowak

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible:
1. You need to know the IP-address (or name) of the computer running the server.
2. Setup a SQL server user (or use SA if you don't care about security).
3. Use the IP-address of the computer running the SQL Server and use the SQL Server user defined in step 2 for the login.